# Create type error when extra properties are present with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible in TypeScript to cause a compile error when *extra* properties are on a type?

For example:

```
interface Expected {
  foo: string;
}

interface Actual {
  foo: string;
  unexpected: number;
}
```

Is there a way with the TypeSystem to fail when I want something of type `Expected`, but not something like `Actual`? I realize the benefits of structural typing and use it for the most part, but there are some times I would like to be extra strict.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936

Comment: @zerkms that indeed looks like a relevant discussion. It seems like it may be possible with the current type system, if you can distill it and provide a working example I'll mark it as the answer. A type alias like `type Exact<t> = ...` would be perfect

Comment: I'm not sure if there are tools to implement it at the moment, but my TS knowledge is very limited.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to throw an error if the *interface* `Actual` does not exactly match the interface `Expected`, or if an given object *instance* contains more properties than those specified in the interface `Expected`?

Comment: You can make a function that will accept a value of type `Expected` and reject a value known to be of type `Actual` (or any value of a type known to have extra properties), but nothing will stop someone from assigning a value of type `Actual` to a variable of type `Expected` and then passing it to your function.  Maybe if we really get [negated types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) in [TS3.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#35-may-2019) that will change.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I want it to be an error provided by the type system